# Retrieving SSL certificate from Azure key vault to Azure app service

Tags: azure, powershell, ssl-certificate, azure-web-app-service, azure-keyvault

I have a SSL certificate in Azure keyvault . I need to install this certicate to Azure app service through powershell.

Comment: According to my understanding, you can configure SSL for your Azure web app with PowerShell : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/scripts/powershell-configure-ssl-certificate. Right?

Comment: But in my scenario  i have that certificate in Azure key valut.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding the issue, we can download the SSL certificate from Azure key vault as pfx file, then use the pfx file to configure SSL for Azure web app

The detailed steps are as below.

1. [Download SSL certificate from Azure key vault](https://www.powershellbros.com/export-keyvault-certificates-azure/). Please note that before running the following command, please configure access policy for the account in the key vault

```
Connect-AzAccount
$cert=Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "your key vault name" -Name ""
$password="Password0123!"
$certBytes = [System.Convert]::FromBase64String($cert.SecretValueText)
$certCollection = New-Object System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate2Collection
$certCollection.Import($certBytes,$null,[System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509KeyStorageFlags]::Exportable)
$protectedCertificateBytes = $certCollection.Export([System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Pkcs12, $password)
$pfxPath = "E:\mycert.pfx"
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($pfxPath, $protectedCertificateBytes)
```

2. Configure SSl

```
New-AzWebAppSSLBinding -WebAppName $webappname -ResourceGroupName $webappname -Name $fqdn `
-CertificateFilePath $pfxPath -CertificatePassword $pfxPassword -SslState SniEnabled
```

Comment: I tried the script. But in AzWebAppSSLBinding if i pass the password directly it shows New-AzWebAppSSLBinding : Operation returned an invalid status code 'NotFound'. But if i pass it as securestring it throws network password is incorrect.But i tried manually via portal i can upload it without any error

Comment: @Learner please append the `-Debug`  parameter to New-AzWebAppSSLBinding to get the detailed error message.

Comment: Thanks mate. Actually that was my misunderstanding . it is working fine now